# Pass same object as const and non-const reference

Tags: c++, constants

The following code compiles with g++ v4.8.1 and outputs `45`, but is its compilation guaranteed based on the standard? Would other compilers complain?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void test(const std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b) {
  b[0] = 45;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v(1,0);
  test(v, v);
  std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
}
```

I understand that there's nothing inherently wrong with the function definition, but when calling `test` with the same object, `v`, I somewhat expected a warning that I was passing a single object as both a `const` and non-`const` reference.

Comment: Why do you expect a compiler to reject this?

Comment: Perhaps it would spot that I pass the same object as both a `const` and non-`const` reference, which seems contradictory.

Comment: @glinka: There's no contradiction. It's perfectly safe and sensible to make a `const` reference to a mutable object, preventing modification via that reference, so the language allows that. The converse, making a mutable reference to a `const` object, wouldn't be safe, so that's not allowed.

Comment: Yes, I understand this; however, I feel the compiler might/should prevent me from making such contradictory claims about an object by passing `v` as both arguments to `test`.

Comment: you make no claims and this is a common scenario. Btw, the compiler may want to warn that the variable `a` is defined but not used in `test()`.

Comment: @glinka From point of view of the function signature declaration it's not known, you're actually passing the same instance to the function as parameter twice. The parameters could be completely unrelated instances, so which _inconsistency_ is introduced by the function declaration actually?

Comment: It's true, but I think a warning would be warranted when you call `test(v, v);`. It would seem like a simple check to make.

Comment: @glinka: It's not making "contradictory claims about an object". A `const` reference means that the reference can't be used to modify the object, not that the object can't be modified at all. This says "`a` refers to a vector you can't change (but which may or may not be changed by other means); `b` refers to one you can change", which has no contradictions.

Comment: @glinka _'but I think a warning would be warranted'_ No need to warn, it's perfectly OK. And there are even valid use cases for such use of that signature. The compiler will throw an error, if you try to pass a `const &` for both parameters, though.

Comment: @Mike Yes, this was what Muscovite Vlad pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem becuase the compiler consideres these two parameters as different references. To understand the code consider the following example

```
int i = 10;
const int &cr = i;
int &r = i;

r = 20;

std::cout << cr << std::endl;
```

Comment: You are the only one who's answered the question I was trying to ask, thank you. I believe you mean `int i` in the first line though. I cannot edit it.

Comment: @glinka Thanks. It was a typo.:)

Comment: @glinka: If your question is more specific than what's actually written in your post, then you should edit your post.

Comment: I thought the title might suffice, but I can see where the confusion arose. Especially as a poster with a paltry 17 rep, you run into these "dumbifications" a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason this shouldn't compile.
Your vector is not const, you can then use it in a const or mutable context.

The same way this works :

```
int i = 42;
const int& const_ref = i;
int& ref = i;
```

Wether you bind the same object or not does not have any incidence here.

You should look at this as if there was a lion in a zoo, the visitors behind windows cannot touch him whereas the trainers can feed him, but it is still the same lion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct. A const reference can be bound to a non-const object. This is of course the case, because why would a non-const object care if a function *doesn't* modify it, which is what the const ensures? (*at least, it ensures that the object is not modified through that particular reference, though it may be modified through another, non-const reference*)

The reverse, however, is not true. You cannot bind a non-const reference to a const object. A const object does in fact care if a function modifies it, which a non-const reference would allow.

Comment: +1 Your answer explains the behavior concisely, and precisely.